# Apache Solr: Can apache solr be used as a third part system for indexing and searching for documents from different websites?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4, github-third-party-apps

I am working on implementing a research web application or portal that integrates different research portal or website using an open source platform called **search kit**. The web application will act as a central point of access to research publications on different research portals. To do this, I also need to implement a third party system that does the following:

1. Searches for documents based on user query on the other different research portals and presents or displays the results to the users on my web application.
2. Index the documents
3. Should be used by system administrators to configure the web application. Whereby system administrators can add,remove or modify the URL of the website Solr is pulling documents from
4. Displays the results to the user in one standard format.

My question is, can apache solr be used to implement the third party system? if not, what open source platform or way would you recommend I used to implement the third party system?

Comment: Solr can be used for indexing and searching the documents. It's unclear what you mean by "configure the web application". As for the 4th point, Solr can return the results in multiple formats, one commonly used is JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited the question to clarify "configure the web application". The other thing I wanted to know, is if Solr could be used to pull documents from different websites to one single site.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Solr seems like a good fit here, but you might need some custom code (apart from configuration) here and there. To go through the points:

1. Querying is one of the main features of Solr, so this is definitely possible.
2. Indexing is handled by Solr.
3. There was a component for Solr called "Data Import Handler" that supported indexing from URLs (see the [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#urldatasource)). However, this was removed from the main Solr distribution, and was moved to a [separate package](https://github.com/rohitbemax/dataimporthandler). This package [doesn't seem to be actively maintained](https://github.com/rohitbemax/dataimporthandler/issues/31) though, so you will probably run into some problems if you decide to use it. The alternative is to develop your document-pulling code yourself.
4. Solr can display the results in multiple formats, but it still might not support the exact format you would like it to be. In this case, you need to build your transformation based on the result from Solr.